# How to Authenticate by appId and key in loopback restapi

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, strongloop

i am wondering how to authenticate app to make requests to endpoints as i am getting 401 errors i have successfully generated app id and appkeys and which should be used as there is no documentation on it.

Comment: This is a legit question, shouldn't be downvoted

Answer (score 2):

The application model is designed to work with oAuth 2.0 which allows the authentication and authorization with client application (client-id/client-secret) and resource owner (username/password). The oAuth 2.0 is under development. Once it's ready, the token endpoint should be able to generate access tokens that carry app and/or user id.